# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]I started Learning Angular JS and Using Editor is Sublime, I am getting Error In chrome Browser: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Please help me out any one Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what file is not found?

Comment: Clearly, the file mentioned somewhere else in this exception was not found.

Comment: Hi @casraf, I added screen shot for reference, Could u please let me know, if you have any idea

Comment: Check if the `/home/user/Desktop/App/js/lib` is valid and you have all the library files located under it. Check the case of `/home/user/Desktop/App/js/lib` too

Comment: It literally shows you the files there are not present... Are they in the directory? Are their permissions allowing them to be accessible? Are you using the right path in the HTML? Do you use relative or absolute paths?

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts references are probably wrong. I guess you copied the location from explorer? You need to reference them as relative to the app. e.g. `/js/lib/angular.js` instead of `/home/user/Desktop/App/js/lib/angular.js`

By doing the latter, it is looking for a directory **within** your app. So the file it's looking for is `/home/user/Desktop/App/home/user/Desktop/App/js/lib/angular.js`

Comment: But I am Getting below Error:

`angular.js:11489 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/user/Desktop/App/tempaltes/login.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`